# /usr/bin/python vs /opt/local/bin/python2.7 on OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

Can you shed some light on the interaction between the Python interpreter distributed with OS X and the one that can be installed through MacPorts?

While installing `networkx` and `matplotlib` I am having difficulties with the interaction of `/usr/bin/python` and `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`. (The latter is itself a soft pointer to `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`)

How can I be certain which Python, pip, and Python libraries I am using at any one time?

More importantly, it appears that installing `matplotlib` is not possible on Lion. It fails with `Requires numpy 1.6 or later to build.  (Found 1.5.1)`. If I upgrade by running `sudo pip install --upgrade numpy`, it does not help. Subsequently attempting to install `matplotlib` (`sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install matplotlib`) still fails with the same (`Requires numpy 1.6...`) message. How can I install matplotlib?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Points to keep in mind about Python**

- If a script `foobar.py` starts with `#!/usr/bin/env python`, then you will always get the OS X Python. That's the case even though MacPorts puts `/opt/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` in your path. The reason is that MacPorts uses the name `python2.7`. If you want to use `env` and yet use MacPorts Python, you have to write `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7`.
- If a script `foobar.py` starts explicitly with `#!/usr/bin/python` or with `#!/opt/local/bin/python2.7`, then the corresponding Python interpreter will be used.

**What to keep in mind about pip**

- To install `pip` for `/usr/bin/python`, you need to run `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip`. You then call `pip` (which will not be installed by `easy_install` in `/usr/bin/pip`, but rather in `/usr/local/bin/pip`)
- To install `pip` for `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`, you need to run `sudo port install py27-pip`. You would then call `pip-2.7`. You will get the pip in `/opt/local/bin`. **Be careful**, because if you type `pip2.7` you will get `/usr/local/bin/pip2.7` (the OS X pip).

**Installing `networkx` and `matplotlib`**

- To install `networkx` for the OS X Python you would run `sudo /usr/local/bin/pip install networkx`. I don't know how to install matplotlib on OS X Lion. It may be that OS X has to stick to `numpy 1.5.1` because it uses it internally.
- To install `networkx` and `matplotlib` for MacPorts-Python, call `sudo pip-2.7 install networkx` and `sudo pip-2.7 install matplotlib`. `matplotlib` installs with a lot of warnings, but it passes.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough answer. You just saved me from quite a headache!

Comment: I'm astounded that this answer doesn't have more upvotes. This is invaluable information that I've struggled to find elsewhere in the past several days.

Answer (score 0):

May I also suggest using Continuum Analytics "anaconda" distribution. One benefit in doing so would be that you won't then need to modify he standard OS X python environment.