# Unable to run ipython notebook or anaconda (conda) commands in terminal

Tags: python, macos, bash, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to get the ipynb running on my Mac, but I am running into some trouble. I specifically want to run the ipynb that comes with Anaconda.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187398/ipython-notebook-fails-to-open) is very close to helping me but I am not sure what to do with the results from checking `which python`, `which python2.7`, `which ipython`.

When I type 'ipython' into the terminal, I get

```
/bin/bash: /Users/me/anaconda/bin/python.app: No such file or directory
```

Anaconda isn't even located in `/Users/me/` so I don't know why bash is looking there when I've put `/usr/local/bin/anaconda/bin` at the front of my path (which I did after that post suggested I check my path variable).

```
$ which anaconda 
/usr/local/bin/anaconda/bin/anaconda

$ which python
/usr/local/bin/anaconda/bin/python`

$ which python2.7
/usr/local/bin/anaconda/bin/python2.7

$ which ipython
/usr/local/bin/anaconda/bin/ipython
```

I tried this to see if it worked, because I'm guessing it is related to the problem I am having:

```
$ conda -h
-bash: /usr/local/bin/anaconda/bin/conda: /Users/me/anaconda/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
```

From the responses I'm getting from bash, it looks like everything is pointing to where it should be, so then why, when I type `ipython` or `conda` into the terminal, do I get those errors?

(Not sure if this is related, but some posts I've seen refer to changing the pip file to point to the version of Python I want, but I am not quite sure where to find the 'pip file'. I went looking for it wherever my pip is stored but I couldn't find a file per say.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely looking in the wrong place. Standard installations would be in /Users/username/anaconda/bin. If you have installed it in /usr/local/bin/anaconda/bin/python you will want to be sure it is in you .bash_profile. In terminal run the following:

```
open .bash_proflie
```

Add the following:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Again the usual Path would be:

```
export PATH="/Users/me/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Be sure to relaunch terminal or run "source .bash_profile"

Comment: Okay I had originally installed anaconda in /Users/me/Software/ and for some reason moved it to /usr/local/bin but I just moved it back, and made sure my .bash_profile had the correct path
export PATH="/Users/me/anaconda/bin:$PATH". but hmmm I am getting the same error I mentioned above..

Comment: If you moved it back to /Users/me/Software/ the PATH still would not match. The Anaconda directory needs to be put into your /Users/me/ directory or the PATH set to /Users/me/Software/anaconda/bin:$PATH. Be sure the anaconda directory is correct in your PATH and not named anaconda2 or  anaconda3.
Additionally you can run "conda info -a" and look to see if PYTHONPATH or PYTHONHOME are set, they should not be as it will look to those paths.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving anaconda to root ("/")

Comment: While this might solve the problem, moving things to root is not the magic solution. As @John Morrison answers indicate, a search path problem is more likely and should fix the problem.